# Truffle migrate no error but does not create build directory

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, react, truffle-compile

I'm trying to develop a simple dapp using ReactJS.I used [Charterhouse/truffle-create-react-app](https://github.com/Charterhouse/truffle-create-react-app) box suggested by truffle website.
The problem is `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate` do not seem to work.
All I get is this:

```
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/SimpleStorage.sol...
```

No errors but build directory is not created.

I'm using ganache-cli and Metamask.
Here's my truffle.js:

```
 module.exports = {
 networks: {
 development: {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8545,
  network_id: '*' // Match any network id
   }
 },
 compilers: {
      solc: '^0.4.24' //added because I have written my own contracts
                      //with this version
   },
   solc: {
     optimizer: {
     enabled: true,
     runs: 200
     }
   }
 }
```

output of truffle network:

```
Contracts have not been deployed to any network.
```

output of truffle version:

```
Truffle v5.0.0 (core: 5.0.0)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v8.10.0
```

I have also tried `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate` with `--reset` and `--all` but no differences.

Comment: Try using truffle migrate --network development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is your truffle.js file. Your version ('^0.4.24') should be defined on a "version" key within the "solc" object. Try this instead:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '^0.4.24',
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

See here for more details on compiler configuration:
https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration]

Comment: thats not solving the issue

Comment: @cryptoKTM what's your issue? My answer seems to have solved Saman's issue (in their case, an error in their truffle.js).

Comment: i needed to compile the solc file with sudo command and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try with this command 'sudo truffle compile'

Comment: If you have to use sudo then it is likely a problem with permissions. Using sudo is a security problem it is better to fix your permissions issues. It is better to use something like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) so you can run node without root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo is the magic word..solved my issue too